# I am installing Ubuntu for the first time, i want it to be my main OS

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, removing

So i have Windows 8.1 or something like that right now but it's a dirty version since i once have sent it to a friend to repair it for me, but this is not the reason why i want to switch, i do it because i was advised by some colleagues.
Not being a master programmer, not being a programmer at all actually, i want to switch to Ubuntu completely and i will be honest, i am a bit terrified by the amount of knowledge needed , but hope will do just fine, i followed the guide to install it, now here is the core question, will windows be removed entirely after i install ubuntu or will i still have it a a bug that tries to watch over my work?
If it's the second one, would you guys advise me to make ubuntu my main OS, and if so, how can i do it, is removing windows completely an option?

Comment: Anything short of a dual boot then Windows will all be gone! Yes it's good option, no bugs as it will completely remove windows

Comment: Don't wipe the whole disk! Keep Windows around to do things that can only be done in Windows. Set up a dual-boot configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you did the installation.

1. Dualboot

If you are running ubuntu as a second os alongside windows, there is nothing to worry about since the the two OSes are not running at the same time. 
Windows cannot watch and monitor your files while ubuntu is running, however, you can *access* your windows content from the ubuntu. To achieve this, you have to mount your windows partition so that you can read and write to it. This guide would be useful.
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access

2. Windows removed completely,

Like I said, if you install wiping the whole disk, then the windows is no longer there. which case the contents on the windows cannot be access unless with some data recovery tool.

NB. Provide a link to the installation guide. And don't be worried about your limited knowledge. Google is your friend.

EDIT:
Use the installation guide from techmint for the dual booting.
https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the help i used https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop?_ga=2.160916669.1088673503.1502296436-651342422.1502296436#0
as a guide, i will definitely wipe the whole disk!

Comment: Which option did you select on step 6?

Comment: I did not do it yet due to my previous concerns, i have just burnt it to my dvd and am about to start the installation following that guide, on step 6 i believe it's Erase disk and Install Ubuntu

Comment: @R.Mir  Don't wipe the whole disk! Keep Windows around to do things that can only be done in Windows. Set up a dual-boot configuration.

Comment: And od your backups first. After erasing and installing is too late for that...

Comment: please use the guide from techmint. And install it alongside. https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

Answer (score 1):

dualboot!

All you need is some disk space for Ubuntu. You choose Ubuntu or Windows on startup. Neither will affect the other (unless you do something yourself).

You'll be able to use your old Windows if you need it and you can start learning Ubuntu step by step.

Ubuntu isn't so hard to learn, it's just different. Maybe you can learn to use it in less time than you learned working with windows.

...there are lots of guides on dualbooting

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to plan this ...

- install virtualbox in Windows,
- install Ubuntu in virtualbox,
- set  up and try to do anything you want to do in Ubuntu
- take note of the programs you are depending on on Windows,
- create a NTFS data partition for Ubuntu and move your files to this partition (if you do not have a D: drive already).

When you got used to Ubuntu switch it around:

- wipe the Windows.
- install Ubuntu
- install virtualbox
- install Windows in virtualbox
- install software in Windows you could not get used to in Ubuntu.
- Use Ubuntu and Windows when needed

When you get to a point you never use Windows convert the data partition to ext4 and delete virtualbox+Windows.

> i am a bit terrified by the amount of knowledge neede

Dual boot is annoying when you really need to use Windows for something specific that does not (seem ;) ) to work for you in Linux. There are 2 things I still need Windows for:

- my Logitech remote control. Only works when I use Windows to connect to it.
- VPN. Part of my work is helping clients with our software but some of them use VPNs that just do not want to work with Linux.

I have a windows in a vbox container just for the VPNs. It is not installed and I copy it over when I need it and remove it when no longer wanted.

---

It took me a year to get used to Linux. (old dude rambling) And I had a background (I used Xenix and Unix even before Linux existed) and I am a programmer. Back then we had to install it from a text based installer and make sure the dependencies where installed. Plus we had no freaking internet. Linux came with a monthly magazine...

I would advice to use above strategy though you can skip the 1st part and install Ubuntu with vbox and Windows in it. Make sure to make a backup before you start.

And you are lucky: you have AskUbuntu to help you out so leech of our experience.